# What information does the operator norm provide?

Tags: linear-transformations, operator-theory, normed-spaces, intuition

I am trying to improve my intuition for the operator norm (of bounded linear transformations between normed spaces). The definition $\sup_{\|x\| = 1} \|Tx\|$ is tells me that $\|T\|$ bounds the magnitude of transformed unit vectors. But I feel slightly dissatisfied because even after taking a course in bounded linear operators, my intuition is lacking.

Could you provide an alternative way to interpret the operator norm or more background such that I can appreciate its rôle in linear analysis?

Comment: Since $T$ is linear, it isn't useful to let $$||T||:= \inf_{x} |T(x)|,$$ because given any $x \neq 0$ you can scale by $c$ so that $|T(cx)|$ is a large as you like.  (If that were the definition, then $||T||= \infty$.)  Thus, the norm of $T$, however it is defined, should somehow be dependent on $x$.

Comment: There isn't really any deeper intuition. Just the 'worst case' scaling.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another one: the norm $M$ of the operator $T$ is the smallest number for which the assertion $\lVert Tx\rVert\leqslant M\lVert x\rVert$ holds for each vector $x$.

Comment: And this $M$ measure the 'contractness' of the operator.